# Python3 - Sort array into specific order

Tags: python, sorting, playing-cards

I'm writing a card game (Kalashnikov) in Python 3 and I want to sort the player's hand. Is it possible to use a sort of dictionary to sort the hands so that the important cards are in the correct order? I have no idea what method would be used.

The object of the game is to get A, K, 4, and 7 in the 4-card hand, so I need to line up the cards in the hand in this order:

- A
- K
- 4
- 7
- [everything else]

If the original hand is 3, K, 7, 2, for instance, after sorting it would look like:

- K
- 7
- 3
- 2
  or:
- K
- 7
- 2
- 3

My current code (simplified to remove unnecessary stuff) is:

```
deck = shuffle()
print("Dealing", end="", flush=True)
    for i in range(4):
        print(".", end="")
        if player == 1:
            hand.append(deck.pop())
            oppHand.append(deck.pop())
        else:
            oppHand.append(deck.pop())
            hand.append(deck.pop())
        sleep(1.25)
    hand = sortHand(hand)
    oppHand = sortHand(oppHand)
    print(" [DONE]")
```

What should the function `sortHand(hand)` be?

Comment: What if there are doubles? Like A4AK8K237, how should sorting then look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a sort of dictionary to sort the hands so that the important cards are in the correct order? I have no idea what method would be used.

Python's `sorted` built-in function (as well as the `list.sort` method) have a `key` parameter which is what you need here: `key` is a function which transforms a value into a "rank" used for sorting, e.g. if you return 0 for "A" and 1 for "K", then "A" will be sorted before "K".

You could just define a dict of ranks, then use that as key:

```py
import collections

ranks = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 5, {
    'A': 0,
    'K': 1,
    '4': 3,
    '7': 4,
})
hand = list('3K72')
print('before', ', '.join(hand))
# => before 3, K, 7, 2
hand.sort(key=lambda card: ranks[card])
print(' after', ', '.join(hand))
# =>  after K, 7, 3, 2
```

Comment: Can I just use `lambda: 4` and then use 0, 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I brain-farted the ranks. The values don't actually matter as long as they sort properly.

Comment: One more thing, I need to check if the hand is an AK47 and for the **GOLDEN KALASHNIKOV** (all the cards are the same suit). I have the cards shown as "A of Clubs" or "3 of Diamonds", so do I use some sort of regex for that?

Comment: @ZacharyBerkowitz That is a separate problem, that should be a separate question all together. However, if you're going to be doing a lot of comparisons, you might (for simplicity's sake) want to set up a class for the different cards that contain both their value and their suits as separate attributes. That way you can just issue say `if card.suit == "clubs"`.

Comment: Could just use `ranks.get` instead of the lambda.

Comment: @superbrain nope, `__missing__` is not called by `dict.get`, so that would return `None` for any "implicitly" ranked value, leading to comparisons between `None` and integers, which will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually take advantage of the standard lib sorted function with the optional key variable:

```
def priority(element):
    if element == 'A':
        return -4
    if element == 'K':
        return -3
    if element == '4':
        return -2
    if element == '7':
        return -1
    return ord( element )

print(sorted(['1','4','K','7'], key=priority))
```

Answer (score 1):

A short one: `hand.sort(key='74KA'.find, reverse=True)`

Note that `find` returns `-1` if the value isn't found, so it maps the characters A, K, 4, 7 to (indices) 3, 2, 1, 0 and all other characters to -1. Which is the reverse of the desired order, hence the `reverse=True` to turn it into the desired order.